# How to set multi-value hidden field from javascript?

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a multi-value text field, the values should be set from javascript on the browser.

For a single value text field, I can just set the value of the hidden field. But for multi-value text field, drupal **will only take the first value** and omit following values even the browser post more than one value.

I insert some `input` tag with same name (nearly, see below) under the form using jquery:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_subscription_id[und][0][value]" value="52e1c1d99c29ec6fd84698b6" />
<input type="hidden" name="field_subscription_id[und][1][value]" value="52e1c1d99c29ec6fd84698b6" />
...
```

data is POST like this (inspect using dev tool of chrome):

```
field_subscription_id[und][0][value]=52e1c1d99c29ec6fd84698b6
field_subscription_id[und][1][value]=52e3de349c29ec6fd84698d4
...
```

After node created, the field `field_subscription_id` will only have the first value.

So, any idea to make this work? ~thx

### EDIT

I define the form from UI, just a normal content type and a text field. I make a ajax request to external site from page, let user select something (from the ajax response), then fill a field of add-node form with the selected ids.

Using the AJAX response, I build a list of `<li>`, each `<li>` has a checkbox, the `form` attribute (HTML5) of the checkbox has been set to the value of form-id of drupal add-node form on this page.

Comment: Please provide more informations eg. what did you on drupal-side, are you using the form_api, how is your form defined etc.?

Comment: I define the form from UI, just a normal content type and a  text field. I make a ajax request to external site from page, let user select something (from the ajax response), then fill a field of add-node form with the selected ids.

Answer (score 1):

Fields will only appear in the $field_state array if they were there when the form was built. (If you inspect the $_POST array directly you should see your values there.)

The solution: When creating the form add enough fields so you don't need to add any more with js.

If you didn't create the form yourself then use hook_form_alter to add more fields.

If you need to be able to add more fields on the fly then you will have to look into the #ajax property. The [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) has some good examples on that.

Also make sure to use the #default_value, not #value property if you need to set a default value for any of the hidden fields as using #value will lock the value to that and stop the client from being able to make any changes.

Comment: I will checkout that module. BTW, if I want to inspect the $_POST array, which function should I look?

Comment: If you have devel installed then dmp($_POST) will do the trick. If not then print_r($_POST) will also do it.